# .load() and relative paths

Tags: jquery, path, jquery-load

`.load()` is giving me trouble. I'm working on a section loader project and I just can't seem to fetch the file that I need.

**What I am trying to achieve**:
`#sectionContainer` is empty on document load, but on document ready it is 'filled' with `Pages1.html`. This is done by a JavaScript file `sections.js`. The JS file and the index.html are NOT in the same folder. Here is the site structure (I am running a lot of projects on my site)

- **main folder**
- *Project 1*
- *Project 2* (sectionLoaderTest/)

  - index.html
  - Pages1.html
  - Pages2.html
  - css/
  - js/

    - sections.js
- *Project 3*
- ...

And the code I use to load Pages1.html on ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sectionContainer").load("../Pages1.html", function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "An error occurred. Status code: ";
            $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + ". Status text: " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried every possible method (/, ./, ., ../, ..) that I know of and nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`./Pages1.html` should work. Tested all accounts for them in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX URLs should be relative to the page you're on, so you want `"Pages1.html"`. What you have in the test case (..Pages1.html) will never work, as that's not a valid reference. (Did you mean to do ../Pages1.html?)