# how to give relative path to jquery load function

Tags: jquery, load

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    function loadContent() {
        $("#includedContent").load("../Projects/menu.html"); //  Not working
    }    
</script> 

<div id="includedContent"></div>

<script>
    loadContent()
</script>
```

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605200/load-and-relative-paths

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#includedContent').load("../Projects/menu.html", function() {
       //stuff
    });
});
```