# jQuery - AJAX load() method isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load a HTML file into a div section, but the load() method doesn't seem to work as when I click the link, the html file opens in a new tab instead of loading into the div tag.

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){
                $('#main-content').load($(this).attr("href"));
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

The 'a' tag:

```
<li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
```

Where I want my html file to be loaded:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 blog-main" id="main-content">
...
</div>
```

How do I make the load() method work?

I'm using Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Try ./about.html
Maybe problem similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605200/load-and-relative-paths

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

That's the default behavior of `a` tag. Instead of setting the html.file to be loaded in href attribute, its better to keep it in custom attribute.

```
 <a href="#" data-page="about.html">ABOUT</a>
```

And in JavaScript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#main-content').load($(this).attr("data-page"));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Plunker sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/FfOorK3vUBwmgeWWZb9r?p=preview)

Comment: It works, there is one bug - preventDefault() instead of Defaults

Comment: it didn't work for me. I don't know why. I've tried it on IE as well.

Comment: This should be not problem of the browser.

Comment: Check in network tab whether the html path is correct or is it returning 404

Comment: apparently, it was the browser's problem. I switched to Firefox and it works   perfectly now.

Comment: I dont think so...works for me in chrome as well..but there isnt anything browser specific here..did you try that plunker in other browser?

Answer (score 0):

try
about.html ensure that the file is in the root of the project

```
<li><a href="./about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
<div class="col-sm-9 blog-main" id="main-content"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#main-content').load($(this).attr("href"));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to stop default action of the event to triggered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#main-content').load($(this).attr("href"));
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){
                $('#main-content').load($(this).attr("href") + ' #elementSelectorThatYouWantToLoad');
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

You have to specify an DOM element that you want to load like,

```
$('#main-content').load($(this).attr('about.html #body');
```